# How to decouple your code when recording logs

Tags: java, spring, logging, aop

I want to keep the audit logs for my service which can add/update/delete user and relevant roles. But I find the audit logs couple to the service code tightly. Actually I think the developer should not be bothered to concern the logs input parameters.

One good method is to use Aop and self-definded annotation to decouple. Something like the followings:

```
@Auditable(actionType = ActionType.ADD, subject = Subject.User) // @Auditable is the annotation defined by me 
@RequestMapping("/addUser")
@ResponseBody
public void
signUp(UserDTO userDTO){
    UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo();
    userInfo.setName(userDTO.getName());
    userInfo.setPassword("11");
    userInfo.setUid(1);
    userInfo.setState(1);
    userInfoService.insert(userInfo);
}
```

the aspect could be like this:

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AuditAspect {

@Resource
private IAuditLogService auditLogService;

@After(value = "@annotation(auditable)")
@Transactional
public void logAuditActivity(JoinPoint jp, Auditable auditable) {
    String targetAuditingUser;
    String actionType = auditable.actionType().getDescription();
    String subject = auditable.subject().getSubject();

    AuditLog auditLog = new AuditLog();
    auditLog.setAppId(1L);
    auditLog.setOperatio(actionType);
    auditLog.setFunctionType(subject);
    auditLog.setCreatedAt(new Date());
    auditLog.setUpdatedAt(new Date());
    auditLogService.insert(auditLog);
}
```

But there is a trouble using aspect. I could not add some service-relevant msg into logs. For example, when I delete a user, I should get the user name and add it into logs.

```
  @Auditable(actionType = ActionType.DELETE, subject = Subject.User)
    @RequestMapping("/delete")
    @ResponseBody
    public void
    delete(int userId){
       // need to record a log “DELETE USER userNameDeleted“， 
       String userNameDeleted = userService.getUserById(userId);

        userInfoService.delete(userId);
    }
```

I need to record a log “DELETE USER Tom“， But userNameDeleted could not be passed to aspect.  So it seems aspect cannot write logs with such sevice-relevant msg(e.g. Tom).

I wonder whether exist methods decoupling the service/application when keeping logs with dynamic msg.

Comment: The question is unclear and you can expect to get close votes. So I suggest you edit the question, explaining (via code!) what "some service-relevant msg" actually means. Which code did you try? What does not work? Error messages? Make the problem reproduceable, please.

Comment: Edit it already.

Comment: You can bind method parameter info (such as `UserDTO userDTO` or `int userId`) from your intercepted methods to advice parameters, if that is what you mean. Then inside your advice you can determine the necessary information by yourself and log it. Is that what you mean? If so, I can provide an example. You do have an unclear way of asking, sorry.